# What am I missing during the Facebook - Auth0 setup that keeps giving me a withe-listing error

Tags: wordpress, facebook, oauth, facebook-login, auth0

I have followed all the step by step instructions provided by Facebook Developers and Auth0 [HERE](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/facebook) to set up the Social login in WordPress via a plugin.

In auth0 when I click try it says it was successful.
[success message Auth0 - SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQRy.png)

But when I put it live our users keep getting this error message when trying to login using the social login button. 
[user error message - SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rBKP.png)

Here is the callback url that I am using for callback in Oauth redirect (Facebook) and Auth0. This is the URL that gives me the successful message.

[Oauth Redirect URL Facebook - SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omp3P.png)

[Auth0 Allow Callback URL - SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFNFE.png)

Is there anything I am missing? Or am I using the wrong callback? I am getting a success message so that is confusing me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in the URL of the login dialog …

Comment: What it ended up being was that the security product that I use to protect my site had a setting that says disable long urls, and since the redirect url was long it was being blocked. But the moment I removed this setting it worked.